# "Organize Imports" keeps removing my imports in Flash Builder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, import

I often use the shortcut for **Organize imports** *(CMD - SHIFT - O)* in Flash Builder. Some times Flash Builder just removes all my imports (not the SDK) and I have to add them manually. Anyone else who have had this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's pretty annoying, too. You can fix it, though. In preferences, go to "Flash Builder" -> "Editors" -> "ActionScript Code". Uncheck the box labeled "Remove unused imports when organizing".

Enjoy!

Comment: I still want it to remove the unused imports, the problem is that sometimes FB removes even used imports.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue when I allow it to collapse imports into an `import something.*` statement - it seems to incorrectly think that some imports are encapsulated by the `*` when they're really not.

---

Disabling that option by setting

`Windows --> Options --> Flash Builder --> Editors --> ActionScript Code --> Organize Imports --> Number of imports needed for...`

to `99` fixed it for me.